# Rubymine can't find Rails on osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I've upgraded `ruby` with `homebrew`. Current version is 2.2.2. Installed `Rails` by gem. Version is 4.2.4.

Trying to build an empty rails project RubyMine stops soon saying

> Can't run 'rails'. Can't find 'rails'.

I've tried both with `RubyMine 7.1` and `RubyMine Eap 8`.

In the shell, obviously everything works perfectly. I think this happens because `RubyMine` uses ruby in `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/bin` instead of `/user/local/bin`. I've tried to export "cellar" folder in $PATH, but that doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I think this happens because RubyMine uses ruby in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/bin instead of /usr/local/bin

That sounds right. Each Ruby install has its own set of (global) gems. Make sure you have rails installed using the Ruby installed by Homebrew (not just the system Ruby).